# eclipse workspace .location file format

Tags: java, eclipse

I need a way to get the directory path of an eclipse project by deserializining the *.location* file found in the eclipe workspace at:

*.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\myproject\.location*

Its contents look something like:
@±‹#¼ %–ç£“¾ URI//file:/D:/proj/myproject              ÀXûó#¼ QóŒ{»wÆ

so I would like to programmatically get the "D:/proj/myproject" string out of it.

Bonus points if the process doesn't use the Eclipse API.

Comment: goto eclipse.org and find the code that writes that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse read this file in the method `LocalMetaArea.readPrivateDescription(..)`.

It uses a SafeChunkyInputStream and DataInputStream for reading it.
It contains UTF8 strings and some integers.

For the complete code see

[org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea at GrepCode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.4.2/org.eclipse.core/resources/3.9.1/org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/LocalMetaArea.java#LocalMetaArea.readPrivateDescription%28org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject%2Corg.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectDescription%29)